# How to copy over an existing JVM from another TC Agent, and create a dedicated Java install for running the local agent

Tags: linux, jvm, virtual-machine, teamcity

I'm trying to use Team City as part of CI/CD. I'm using a linux box. I've downloaded the TC Agent onto the linux box and set it up. Now, I need to download and install JVM. There are other TC Agents being used by others in the team. I've been recommended to copy the JVM those Agents are using to my agent but I'm abit unsure as to do this. Anyone have any recommendations as to how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can archive JAVA_HOME from one agent, copy to you and unarchive, and set up the JAVA_HOME env value
2. what I highly recommend, find the java version on the one agent(`java -version`),  install it where you need it.